# FilePond is not defined

Tags: filepond

I copy all code from  https://unpkg.com/filepond@4.4.12/dist/filepond.min.js
and past into chrome console opened on this (StackOverflow) website(for example). I see in console FilePond object is created. I have an access.

[image]

But if I do the same on my website -  `filePond is not defined`
I have no idea what script on my website can broke FilePond initialization.

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe you're trying to access it before the file has loaded? Or you have loaded requirejs in which case FilePond exposes an AMD module.

Comment: I did not upload a file. Just copied text to console and check  avalability of FilePond object. Yes, requirejs is using on my website. Is it mean I cant see FilePond object in  window global vars?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to require it as a module